# Firebase Auth Login not showing logged in user name

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using firebase web authentication to log users into my website which works perfectly fine - but I want to be able to show the name of the user logged in. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

When a user signs up, it will be written with some basic fields (email, uniqueID, etc) to the Firebase Authentication DB (which you have access to, but you don't have full control of, since it's controlled by the Firebase Auth system).

Once your brand new user is created, you'll get a `UserCredential` object with basic information of your user. Use the uniqueID field (`UserCredential.user.uid`) to write your user details with as many fields as you want (username, email, fullName, address, preferences, etc) to your Firebase database (realtime DB or cloud Firestore). I think it's a good practice to store under a document with the uniqueID created by the Auth system.

Once you've done that, and that users logins in at a later time, you'll get another userCredential object that contains the uniqueID for that user.

You'll use that uniqueID to access your database where you stored your users details and you will be able to retrieve all the data that you want.

See the code below (I'm using React): uppon a successful signUp, we get a UserCredential object, which we can use to read the uniqueId `uid` that it was just created, and use that to create a document in our database with that same id. We can add as many fields as we want. In this case, I added username (which I'm getting from my signup form) and email (which I'm getting directly from the UserCredential object).

[UserCredential docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth#.UserCredential)

[Create User with Password and Email docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#createUserWithEmailAndPassword)

```
handleSubmit(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    const { email, passwordOne} = this.state;

    // SIGN UP FUNCTION
    this.props.firebase.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, passwordOne)

    // SAVING USER DETAILS TO MY DATABASE
    .then((UserCredential) => {
      const username = this.state.username;
      this.props.firebase.db.collection('users').doc(UserCredential.user.uid)
        .set({
          username: username,
          email: UserCredential.user.email
        })
        .then( () => {
          this.setState({ ...INITIAL_STATE });
          this.props.history.push('/');
          }
        )
        .catch(error => {
          this.setState({ error });
          }
        );
      }
    )
    .catch(error => {
      this.setState({ error });
      }
    );
  }
```